# creating a vbs script function for sending email with attachment

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to scripting and I'm creating an automated task inside openoffice I'm having issue with the crude basic language but I found a excel macro written in vba that does what I need now im trying to convert this to a useable vbscript that can be executed from the command prompt with something like email.vbs mailto subject filetoattach

```
Dim cdoMsg As New CDO.Message

With cdoMsg
    With .Configuration.Fields
        .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod).Value = cdoSendUsingPort
        .Item(cdoSMTPUseSSL).Value = True
        .Item(cdoSMTPServerPort).Value = 465
        .Item(cdoSMTPServer).Value = "smtpserver"
        .Item(cdoSendUserName).Value = "wolverinewest@wolverinetruckgroup.com"
        .Item(cdoSendPassword).Value = "mypass"
        .Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate).Value = cdoBasic
        .Update
    End With
    .From = "myemail"
    .To = "emailto"
    .Subject = "Some more really spiffy mail for you!"
    .TextBody = "please find attachment"
    .AddAttachment App.Path & "attachment"

    On Error Resume Next
    .Send
End With

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "CDO error " & Hex$(Err.Number) & vbNewLine & Err.Description, _
           vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation, _
           Caption
Else
    MsgBox "Mail sent!", vbOKOnly, Caption
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntax for launching in windows if using wscript is;

```
wscript.exe "C:\path\example.vbs" "your email address" "who your sending it to" "your subject" "your body text & vbCRLF & for new line" "c:\path\attachment"
```

the "" are required because the spaces through off the order and windows send errors if spaces are in the path

```
dim mailto
dim mailfrom
dim subject
dim body
dim attachment
mailfrom = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
mailto = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
subject = WScript.Arguments.Item(2)
body = WScript.Arguments.Item(3)
attachment = WScript.Arguments.Item(4)


Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
emailObj.From     = mailfrom
emailObj.To       = mailto
emailObj.Subject  = subject
emailObj.TextBody = body

emailObj.AddAttachment attachment

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration

emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.mysmtp.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = "myUsername"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = "myPassword"
emailConfig.Fields.Update

emailObj.Send

If err.number = 0 then Msgbox "email sent"
```

Answer (score 1):

VBScript has no constants built in so you have to look the constants in VBA's object browser (Alt + F11 - F2 in Excel) and use the number. There is only one datatype in VBScript so no dimming anything as anything (eg `Dim x as string` only `Dim x`). VBscript only can late bind so no `Dim cdoMsg As New CDO.Message` - have to `set cdomsg = CreateObject("cdo.message")`.

There is nothing crude about VBScript.

Fields will have default values taken from Outlook Express or Windows Mail but are not set on Windows 10 as it doesn't have either of those two programs.

Here's the bare minimum

```
Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
emailObj.From     = "dcandy@gmail.com"
emailObj.To       = "dcandy@gmail.com"
emailObj.Subject  = "Test CDO"
emailObj.TextBody = "Test CDO"

emailObj.AddAttachment "c:\windows\win.ini"

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration

emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = "Username"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = "Password"
emailConfig.Fields.Update

emailObj.Send

If err.number = 0 then Msgbox "Done"
```

Comment: im not saying vba is crude im saying openoffice basic language is crude

Comment: how do i edit this for command line streaming ie. wscript.exe "C:\Wherever\email.vbs" "subject" "body" "attachment" what im doing is emailing a spreadsheet every time its updated to a group email and I want to automate the process to save time usually all I do is send an email with subject as "filename todays date" and body of "here are todays updates" and the attachment is the file being updated being how the file name changes with every update I need to be able to supply it to the script. I don't know vbs that well still learning so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Download help - https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764.  And searches like this https://www.google.com.au/search?q=vbscript+site%3Amsdn.com.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can send email with attachment using VBS:**

```
Function sendEmail()
    filePath = "C:\Users\shubham\OneDrive\Pictures\Camera Roll\myImage.jpg"
    Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
    objMessage.Subject = "Your VBS EMAIL"
    objMessage.From = "xyz@private.com" 
    objMessage.To = "abc@gmail.com" 
    objMessage.AddAttachment filePath
    objMessage.TextBody = "My Text"
    Set objConfig = objMessage.Configuration
    objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
    objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "serverXXXXX.web-XYZABC.com"
    objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "USERNAME@private.com"
    objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "MYPASSWORD_XXXXXXXX"
    'Server port (typically 25)
    objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
    objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = true
    objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    objConfig.Fields.Update
    objMessage.Send
End Function

sendEmail()
```